# Component with JSX prop fails on ezyme shallow wrapping

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, enzyme

I am trying to test `Select` component from material-UI which takes **JSX** prop `input`.

I get the following error `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s`.

Removing `input` line passes the test, but that's not the purpose.

Generic info:

- I am using enzyme on react 16
- This is at attempt for shallow snapshot of a component using shallow eznyme method and enzyme-to-json
- This fails only on testing and the way is implemented is based on this example https://codesandbox.io/s/qicub?file=/demo.js line 70

Component:

```
const SelectControl = ({
  classes,
  customClass,
  options,
  controlValue,
  setControlValue,
}: Props) => (
  <FormControl className={customClass}>
    <Select
      value={controlValue}
      onChange={(event) => setControlValue(event.target.value)}
      input={<SelectInput />}
  >
      {!!placeHolder && (
        <MenuItem value="" disabled className={classes.dropdownItem}>
          <Typography variant="subtitle1">{placeHolder}</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
      )}
      {options.map(({ value, description }) => (
        <MenuItem value={value} key={value} className={classes.dropdownItem}>
          <Typography variant="subtitle1">{description}</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
);
```

Test:

```
test('renders correctly WITHOUT the optional props', () => {
    // WHEN
    const tree = shallowSnapshot(<SelectControl {...commonProps} />);

    // THEN
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

shallowSnapshot implementation:

```
const shallowSnapshot = (Component) =>
  toJson(shallow(Component), {
    mode: 'shallow',
  });
```